# Every time we add new Data to Hive, Do we have to build the kylin cube again

Tags: hive, kylin

If add more rows to hive table, Do we have to run a map reduce job again to build the cube if we create a cube without partition Date column

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to re-run your MapReduce job after adding additional rows.

CUBE creates a subtotal of all possible combinations of the set of columns you mention while running job.

After adding more rows, sub total and/or possible number of combinations might increase based upon the data in new rows.